# Adding Point layer attribute to subsequent Lines segment using QGIS

Tags: fields-attributes, points-to-line

I have multiple point shapefiles which have values like ID , Strom ID , windspeed, Lat , lon etc.

I used Points to Path tool to convert these points into storm tracks ( See fig 1) using ID as order field and StormID 1 as Group field.
But at the end all other information dissolved and I left with StormID1 , Start and End Columns ( See fig 2). I know this is what QGIS do based upon Order by and Group by field.

But I am interested in getting at least Windspeed information along the storm tracks after each points. I mean if possible to get values of point 2104 along the line till point 2105 and then point 2105 values till point 2106. If not all possible at least one column let say windspeed. ( see fig 3 for visual help).

I have tried join by location and join by attribute but it is picking first value which is not correct.

Let me know for further clarification:
[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

[image: Fig3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have different values for each segment of the line (for each one of the connections from one point to the next). However, you get one line that can have only one value per attribute.

In this case, [explode the line](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=explode%20line#explode-lines). You will get separate line features for each segment. Than you can use these lines to join with the point attributes as you already did for the dissolved line. But this time, you have a separate line for each point.